# Escaping the exclamation point in grep?

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I have this full line (the rpm command into awk below) that I want to grep out from certain files, including the quotes. I can't seem to be able to get the right output when I try grep, and grep -F. I tried deleting part of the tail end of line from the grep statement and it seems like the "!" causing the problems. I tried wrapping the string in single quotes and there is no luck as well. Thank you.

```
rpm -qVa | awk '$2!="c" {print $0}'
```

Comment: Adding an example of the grep line in full may be helpful. I imagine it is something like this: `grep "rpm -qVa | awk '$2!="c" {print $0}"`

Comment: If you are getting "event not found", turn off the `histexpand` option in Bash. IIRC single quotes should guard against that, though.

Answer (score 11):

You have a few options.

1. Use single quotes - when you need a literal single quote, just drop out of single quotes, add one with a backslash, and then go back in:

   `grep 'rpm -qVa | awk '\''$2!="c" {print $0}'\' filename`
2. Use a POSIX string:

   `grep $'rpm -qVA | awk \'$2!="c" {print $0}\'' filename`
3. Use a less-specific pattern:

   `grep 'rpm -qvA | awk .$2.="c" {print $0}.' filename`

   or, if you have checks for `$2=="c"` as well as `$2!="c"`, you could do something like this:

   `grep 'rpm -qvA | awk .$2[^=]="c" {print $0}.' filename`

I would go with the POSIX string, or maybe the plain single-quote option - which has the debatable advantage of working in other shells, like `dash`.

Answer (score -1):

A backslash should do the trick

```
rpm -qVa | awk '\$2!="c" {print $0}'
```